# Adding/Removing event listener -

Tags: removeeventlistener

Firstly, i need to have the button text display "Machine is on" after i click it.
then, I need to make it display "Machine is off" - as it was initially.
here is the code i've tried.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.off');

const buttonOn = function() {
  this.textContent = "Machine is on"
};
const buttonOff = function() {
  this.textContent = "Machine is off"
};

btn.addEventListener('click', buttonOn);
btn.removeEventListener('click', buttonOn);
```

```html
<section class="preview">
</section>

<button class="off">Machine is off</button>
```

Comment: i tried having just one const (ex: const buttonState = function(){

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you've described, you don't need to remove the event listener. Just listen for the click and switch the text back and forth.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.off'),
  buttonOn = false;

const buttonClick = function() {
  if (buttonOn) this.textContent = "Machine is off";
  else this.textContent = "Machine is on";    
  
  buttonOn = !buttonOn;
};

btn.addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
```

```html
<section class="preview">
</section>

<button class="off">Machine is off</button>
```